# Data order by which table its in SQL

Tags: sql, data-mining

So this is a weird one.

I have a search for a person that exists in the table "profile"  and we have people that are allowed to become like a fan of a person.  They can favorite them.

[Profile]
[uid, first, last, location]

[Favorite]
[A][B]

The profile table consists of some basic information (more than that but thats all that needs to be displayed) and the favorite table consists of 2 unique ids.  A has B as a favorite. (A -> B).  From the select results i want to display different messages (like this is your friend group, this is the other results).

```
SELECT P.firstname, P.lastname, P.location, P.uid, 2 AS type
FROM profile AS P
    JOIN favorites AS F
    ON F.A = 'myid' and F.B = P.uid
WHERE (P.firstname LIKE 'mich%' or P.lastname LIKE 'mich%')
```

So this first one gets all of the people that i consider my favorite.  Second, how do i get a general result and append it to SUCH THAT there are no duplicate results?

I tried something like this.

```
SELECT P.firstname, P.lastname, P.location, P.uid, 2 AS fan
FROM profile AS P
    JOIN favorites AS F
    ON F.A = P.uid and F.B = 'myid'
WHERE (P.firstname LIKE 'micha%' or P.lastname LIKE 'micha%')
  UNION
SELECT P.firstname, P.lastname, P.location, P.uid, 1 AS fan
FROM profile AS P
    JOIN favorites AS F
    ON F.A != P.uid and F.B = 'myid'
WHERE (P.firstname LIKE 'micha%' or P.lastname LIKE 'micha%')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can combine that into one simple query using a case statement and a left join:

```
select p.firstname, p.lastname, 
   p.location, p.uid, 
   case when f.A is null then 1
   else 2
       end as type
from profile as p
left join favorites as f
 on p.uid = f.B and f.A = 'myid'
where p.firstname like 'mich%' or p.lastname like 'mich%'
```

This will search profiles for your WHERE clause, and if it matches your favorites join the type field will evaluate to a 2, otherwise it will be one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want...

```
SELECT P.firstname, P.lastname, P.location, P.uid, CASE F.A = P.uid THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS fan
FROM profile AS P
    LEFT JOIN favorites AS F
    ON  F.B = P.uid
WHERE (P.firstname LIKE 'micha%' or P.lastname LIKE 'micha%')
```